# Discover the reason why two iterated integrals with different orders are not equal

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Consider on $[0,1]^{2}$ the function defined by $$f(x,y):=\dfrac{x^{2}-y^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}.$$

I have computed out the iterated integrals are not the same if we swap the order of the integral. That is, $$\int_{0}^{1}\Big(\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dx\Big)dy\neq \int_{0}^{1}\Big(\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dy\Big)dx.$$ Indeed, we could see that $$LHS=-\dfrac{\pi}{4}\ \text{while}\ RHS=\dfrac{\pi}{4}.$$

However, I want to figure out why they are not equal in the sense of measure theory. That is, there must be something that violates Fubini theorem.

I tried to figure it out in the following way:

Firstly we can see that $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$ and $x$, and thus is measurable with respect to $x-$region (if treating $y$ as a constant) and vice versa. So the only thing left is that $f(x,y)$ is not integrable with the product measure on $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

I tried to show $$\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}|f(x,y)|dxdy=\infty,$$ in the following way. Firstly, we replace $x:=r\cos\theta$ and $y:=r\sin\theta$, so that
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,1]\times [0,1]}|f(x,y)|dxdy&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{|\cos^{2}(\theta)-\sin^{2}(\theta)|}{r^{2}}rdrd\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\cos^{2}(\theta)-\sin^{2}(\theta)|d\theta\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{r}dr
\end{align*}

Now the problem comes, $\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{r}dr=\infty$, and thus the whole integral is $\infty$.

Is my proof correct? Thank you!

Comment: This looks correct to me, indeed just by looking at the function we can see that there are problems around: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Comment: @HenryLee oh! right! Yeah the function, considered as two variables has problem at $(0,0)$, since I remeber this is a classic calculus exericse that the limit of this function when $(x,y)$ goes to $(0,0)$ is infinite, just doing the cooridanate change in my post.

Comment: @HenryLee thanks! Do you want to post a solution exactly like what you suggested in the comment? so that I can accept and upvote. You don't need to be any more detailed. :) Thank you so much.

Comment: It is not true that $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is the same as the disk  $ \{(r,\theta): 0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1, 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant 2\pi\}$, but the sector $ \{(r,\theta): 0 \leqslant r \leqslant 1, 0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi/2\}$ is a  subset of $ [0,1]\times[0,1]$ and you can carry out your argument noting that $\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]} |f| \geqslant \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 \ldots$.

Comment: @RRL yeah. You are right, I was also worried about this. Thanks for the confirmation

Comment: You had the right idea, of course.

Comment: @RRL Thank you :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Henry Lee suggested, my above proof is okay. But he also pointed out that $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)=\infty.$$ One could see this using polar coordinate again.

Therefore, the continuity of $f(x,y)$ is problematic around $(0,0)$. Hence, $f(x,y)$ is actually not a continuous function on $x-$region or $y-$region, since for example in $x-$region when $y=0$, the thing became subtle. This problem finally causes the non-integrability of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: To be precise I would not say non-integrability is caused by discontinuity.  There are discontinuous and unbounded functions that are integrable.  In this case the integrand grows unboundedly and sufficiently fast near the origin so that it is not integrable.

Comment: @RRL thanks for the comment! It makes my answer whole :))

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: In the first part, notice that over the path $t\mapsto (t,0)$ your map exploits to $+\infty$ but if you choose the path $t\mapsto (0,t)$ then your map exploits to $-\infty$. So the first part, it is not correct.